# Vue 2: Minify JS files using Terser

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, compression, minify, terser

I want to compress my js files using Terser Plugin.
Here is my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0",
    "vuex": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
}
```

Then I created a webpack.config.js to add the plugin as written in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser-webpack-plugin)

```
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
};
```

When I run my project, it doesn't minify my js files. Also, the docs says that we should `run webpack via your preferred method.`. How do I run the webpack? Appreciate all help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should put such configuration in vue.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      minimize: true.
      // etc...
    }
  }
}
```

Cf. [Documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration)